# Cannot clone git repo using GitLab CI runners token (version 8.12.0-rc6-ee)

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm working with GitLab Enterprise Edition 8.12.0-rc6-ee.
I was using the CI runners token to perform git clone operations for private repositories without problem.
However, since a few days ago I cannot do it anymore and instead I'm getting an "Authentication failed" error.

Here is the command:
git clone "https://gitlab-ci-token:*******@gitlab.com/my-company/some-project.git"

Could it be that there is some change in how Git CI/CD works for the latest versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way of authenticating introduced in Gitlab 8.12. You can read about it in [their documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html).

Gitlab is suggesting to use git submodules with `../../user_or_group/project.git` instead of the proper url and to initialize them in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` (try it but it does not work for me).